# How to overwrite Bookmarks?

Tags: vba, ms-word

The bookmarks in Word keep getting deleted.

I want it to "overwrite" the last input not add it.

```vb
Dim NAME As Range
Set NAME = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Username").Range
NAME.Text = Me.TextName.Value

Dim Surname As Range
Set Surname  = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("UsernameSurname").Range
Surname.Text = Me.TextSurname.Value
```

Comment: See Inserting text at a bookmark without deleting the bookmark https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/MacrosVBA/InsertingTextAtBookmark.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code doesn't delete the bookmarks - it simply inserts content after them.

To *update* the bookmarks, you might use, for example:

```
Call UpdateBookmark("Username",Me.TextName.Value)
Call UpdateBookmark("UsernameSurname",Me.TextSurname.Value)
```

coupled with:

```
Sub UpdateBookmark(StrBkMk As String, StrTxt As String)
Dim BkMkRng As Range
With ActiveDocument
  If .Bookmarks.Exists(StrBkMk) Then
    Set BkMkRng = .Bookmarks(StrBkMk).Range
    BkMkRng.Text = StrTxt
    .Bookmarks.Add StrBkMk, BkMkRng
  End If
End With
Set BkMkRng = Nothing
End Sub
```